# Getting raw data of files (eg. PDFs, .docx, .png, etc) via JavaScript, and saving them to a server disk

Tags: html, blob, arraybuffer, raw-data

I'm running a front-end app that allows users to enter a destination URL that can be any file type really. PDFs, or Word documents, or images.

The app only needs to run in Chrome, and so I'd like to make the request to the file on the front end, and then send that data to a server for storage (and later, for downloading).

I'm confused on how to do that. Should it be done via a Blob, ArrayBuffer? Any tips or directions would be great. Have been having trouble finding tutorials on this.